# How to use jQuery click not jumping to top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following jQuery code for open my shop URL in a new tab windows when user click any part of page :

```
    function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}

function setCookie(c_name, value) {
    var exdays = 1;
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setHours(exdate.getHours() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function checkCookie() {
    var username1 = getCookie("tabligh1");
    var username2 = getCookie("tabligh2");
    var usernam = "sendshod";
    if (username1 == null | username2 == null) {
        window.open('#', '_parent', 'toolbar=1,location=1,directories=1,status=1,menubar=1?,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');
        window.focus();
    }
    if (username1 == "" | username1 == null) {
        if (window.open('http://shop.url')) {
            window.focus();
            setCookie("tabligh1", usernam);
        }
    }
}
// document.onclick = checkCookie;
jQuery(document).click(function (event) {
    if (!jQuery(event.target).is('.hamyar_area, .hamyar_area *')) {
        checkCookie();
    }
})
if ((window.XMLHttpRequest == undefined) && (ActiveXObject != undefined)) window.onload = checkCookie;
```

When user click in page , a # character add end of correct URL like this:

before click : domain.com
after click : domain.com/#

And when # character add to end of URL, page jumping to top of page.

I want to use this jquery code but I don't want when user click on the page, page don't jumping to the top.